# What am I? Farmers down under, and scientists, think I'm a menace

Tags: riddle

> Farmers down under, and scientists,
>
> think I'm a menace.
>
> And as for fruit, forget 5 a day,
>
> 100 a day will make you feel alive.
>
> But don't worry, I'll be back soon.
>
> Now excuse me, it's high time we get out
>
> of this ghost town.

What am I?

Clue:

> Sorry about that drain damage, but it's crunch time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are

> Crash Bandicoot

Farmers down under, and scientists, think I'm a menace.

> The main antagonist of the game is a scientist, and bandicoots are Australian animals that can spread disease to livestock.

And as for fruit, forget 5 a day, 100 a day will make you feel alive.

> In the game, collecting 100 Wumpa Fruits will award the player an extra life.

But don't worry, I'll be back soon.

> Crash Bandicoot games will be remastered for PS4 next year.

Now excuse me, it's high time we get out
of this ghost town.

> "Ghost Town" is a level in the game.

Sorry about that drain damage, but it's crunch time!

> Drain Damage is a boss level where you fight Crunch.

Answer (score 4):

Farmers down under, and scientists,

> The Queensland and Mediterranean fruit fly are a concern for both
>  farmers and scientists of Australia.

think I'm a menace.

> They cause significant damage to crops.

And as for fruit, forget 5 a day,

> Apples, peaches, nectarines, apricots, etc. are threatened.

100 a day will make you feel alive.

> Besides feeding on the fruit they lay their eggs within, so they
>  literally *come alive* within the fruit.

But don't worry, I'll be back soon.

> Although currently under control, a new populations has been recently
>  spotted.

Now excuse me, it's high time we get out

> A "high time" is what flies are having when they move about.

of this ghost town.

> This could refer to the damage they've done to some rural economies.

Comment: Good try, but not what I was looking for.